# How to specify parameters to a WebRequest

Tags: c#, oauth, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send parameters to an URL.

This works nicely if I DO NOT include "dict".

But when I add dict in brackets (as below) I notice that my var "url" does NOT contain the string startdate or enddate.

Should I be specifying this in some other way?

```
   OAuthRequest client = OAuthRequest.ForRequestToken("xxxxxx", "yyyyyyyy");
            client.RequestUrl = "https://api.drum.is/assets/audusd/juice/"; 
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {
             {"startdate", "20140101"},
             {"enddate", "20140106"}
    };
    string auth = client.GetAuthorizationQuery(dict);
    var url = client.RequestUrl + "?" + auth; 
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Accept = "application/json, text/javascript";            

    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Check the `GetAuthorizationQuery` Method.

Comment: @Inanikian  I have. No example given of how to do it

Comment: Did you found a solution? I would like to know too